# What is the correct return in a function that modifies a potential r-value reference?

Tags: c++11, move, rvalue-reference, perfect-forwarding

Conceptually and practice, what is the correct way to return the modified value of a function that *potentially* takes a r-value reference.

```
template<class Vector>
??? add_element(Vector&& v){
    v.emplace_back(1.);
    return ???(v);
}
```

Intuition tells me this, (because I don't loose information of the original type)

```
template<class Vector>
Vector&& add_element(Vector&& v){
    v.emplace_back(1.);
    return std::forward<Vector>(v);
}
```

but among other possibilities is

```
template<class Vector>
Vector& add_element(Vector&& v){
    v.emplace_back(1.);
    return v;
}
```

or even these ones, (based on this https://pizer.wordpress.com/2009/04/13/c0x-do-people-understand-rvalue-references/ )

```
template<class Vector>
Vector // or typename std::decay<Vector>::type 
add_element(Vector&& v){
    v.emplace_back(1.);
    return v; // or std::forward<Vector>(v); 
}
```

**What is the most generic way of returning the modified passed argument?**

Answer (score 5):

In a more general situation with forwarding references, how you return depends on what you want to do.

Luckily, in this case, all choices except one are wrong (dangerous, fragile, etc), so that makes it easy, because you are returning a container.

```
template<class Vector>
Vector add_element(Vector&& v){
  v.emplace_back(1.);
  return std::forward<Vector>(v); 
}
```

this is what I typically do.  It can take a temporary, and if so moves the temporary into the return value.

If it takes a non-temporary, it modifies it and returns a reference of the same category.

```
template<class Vector>
Vector&& add_element(Vector&& v){
  v.emplace_back(1.);
  return std::forward<Vector>(v); 
}
```

This is unfortunetally a bad idea.  Reference lifetime extension doesn't commute over function calls, so

```
auto&& v = add_element(make_vector());
```

results in a leaking reference.  Assuming your types are cheap to move (like vector), returning a moved-into temporary copy is a trivial cost that enables reference lifetime extension.

"But", you say, "I don't use `auto&&`".  Well, for containers, `for(:)` loops *do*, and the reference dangles.  So as a rule, *never return a container by rvalue reference*.

```
template<class Vector>
Vector& add_element(Vector&& v){
  v.emplace_back(1.);
  return v;
}
```

This both loses type information and prevents reference lifetime extension.

Never return a temporary by `&` if you can help it.

This behaves strangely when passed an lvalue:

```
template<class Vector>
std::decay_t<Vector> add_element(Vector&& v){
  v.emplace_back(1.);
  return std::forward<Vector>(v); 
}
```

as it both copies and modifies its argument.  I'm uncertain why you'd want to do this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, even if the argument is not a container the first option is the case which gives the must uncompromising performance and generality. no?

Comment: @alfC If you have expensive to move objects, clearly it isn't uncompromising performance.  All length-mutable `std` containers are cheap to copy, so that doesn't apply here.

Comment: also "never return a container by rvalue reference.": as a counterexample, `std::optional::operator*()` or `std::optional::value()` _do_ return by rvalue reference.

Comment: I guess it could be reworded as "return by rvalue reference *with great care*" or "never bind an rvalue reference to a result of a function that returns an rvalue reference". As an example, if you have `f(g(h(make_vector())))`, you probably don't want to move-construct return values each time, following the C++ approach of not paying for what you don't use. But if you assign such sequence of calls to something, it should be `T` (not `T&&`  or `const T&`), as in `auto r =f(g(h(make_vector())))`.

Comment: And thanks for the "range-based for" example! Much appreciated.

Comment: @Yakk, do you mean that if the type is not movable then the first option will end up being more expensive than other options (which?).

Comment: @Yakk, by the way, I do use `auto&&`. Yes, specially in loops.